# Appstore reviews are not loading

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

https://apps.apple.com/
Appstore reviews are not properly loading when scrolling down the reviews. Reviews in the top are showing as expected, but when I scrolled down the page is keep on loading. When I checked the network call, it is throwing 429 "too many request" error.

Here is the api used in appstore for getting reviews,

[https://amp-api.apps.apple.com/v1/catalog/in/apps/{appId}/reviews?l=en-GB&offset=50&platform=web&additionalPlatforms=appletv%2Cipad%2Ciphone%2Cmac](https://amp-api.apps.apple.com/v1/catalog/in/apps/%7BappId%7D/reviews?l=en-GB&offset=50&platform=web&additionalPlatforms=appletv%2Cipad%2Ciphone%2Cmac)

I am using the above api for fetching appstore reviews based on appId. It is giving 429 now. Any fix available for this issue? . If not, Is there any other api available to fetch app store reviews based on appId?

Comment: Happens to me sometimes. Try using the App Store Connect app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can use app store connect app..but thing is I need api for fetching reviews.